# XML (De)Serialization of List

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

currently I'm trying to serialize and deserialize some of my classes to XML. The one way (List -> XML) works perfectly (see example below). The other way won't work correctly.
The class which I wan't to deserialize contains itself another List of another class. This is also correctly in the XML file. But when I deserialize the class it won't work.

In the example below this means the class Foo gets correctly serialized with its List of Bars. But when I deserialize the XML-File only FooString and the other Properties gets correctly serialized. The List of Bar is everytime empty. The Debugger also won't get there anytime.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance!

**the Main Object looks like this:**

```
[XmlInclude(typeof (Bar))]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Foo")]
public class Foo()  : IFooInterface
{
    [XmlElement("FooString")]
    public string FooString
    {
        // For simplifaction auto proerty, normally with
        // backing field
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Some other properties for the xml
    // ...

    // Dirty Hack to serialize the List, because an Interface could not be serialized
    // I've already tried to remove this tag, to replace it with [XmlElement("BarList")], but nothing works
    [XmlArray("BarList")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Bar", Type = typeof(Bar))]
    public List<Bar> XmlBarList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.BarList.Select(bar => bar as Bar).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
            this.BarList = new ObservableCollection<IBarInterface>(value);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IBarInterface> barList;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public ObservableCollection<IBarInterface> BarList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.barList;
        }
        set
        {
            // For simplification removed Notification Proerties
            this.barList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**The nested class looks like this:**

```
[XmlType("Bar")]
public class Bar : IBarInterface
{
    [XmlElement("BarString")]
    public string BarString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Some other properties for the xml 
    // ...
}
```

**The class which (de)serializes the classes:**

```
public class FooBarProvider()
{
    // Won't work
    // the BarList of any Foo item is everytime
    // empty. 
    public List<Foo> Load()
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader("PathToTheXml.xml");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>));
        var list = (List<Foo>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    // Works
    public void Save(List<Foo> fooList)
    {
       var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>));
       var writer = new StreamWriter("PathToTheXml.xml");
       serializer.Serialize(writer, fooList);
       writer.Close();
    }
}
```

**The XML File which is generated:**

```
<ArrayOfFoo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Foo>
    <BarList>
      <Bar>
        <BarString>Hello Bar!</BarString>
      </Bar>
    </BarList>
    <FooString>Hello Foo!</FooString>
  </Foo>
</ArrayOfFoo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use XmlArray.  It create an extra set of nodes.  Use XmlElement instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ArrayOfFoo aof = new ArrayOfFoo() {
                foo = new Foo() {
                     FooString = "Hello Foo!",
                     barList = new List<BarList>() {
                        new BarList() {
                          bar = new Bar() {
                              barString = "Hello Bar!"
                          }
                        }
                     }
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfFoo));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, aof);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfFoo));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            ArrayOfFoo newAof = (ArrayOfFoo)xs.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "ArrayOfFoo")]
    public class ArrayOfFoo
    {
        [XmlElement("Foo")]
        public Foo foo { get; set; }
    }

     [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Foo")]
    public class Foo
    {
        [XmlElement("FooString")]
        public string FooString { get; set; }


        [XmlElement("BarList")]
        public List<BarList> barList { get; set; }

    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BarList")]
    public class BarList
    {
        [XmlElement("Bar")]
        public Bar bar { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Bar")]
    public class Bar
    {
        [XmlElement("BarString")]
        public string barString { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "BarString")]
    public class BarString
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }​
}
​
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But this didn't worked also. I've tried it. I've also tried to remove the tags and let it auto decide. But everything I do - it won't work :/ Do you have another approach?

Comment: You really don't need both ArrayofFoo and Foo.  They can be combined into one class.  Also BarList and Bar can be combined into one class.

Answer (score 0):

Oh damnmit!

I see my mistake.

Through my dirty "hack" for serializing the Interface Object it will create an temporary object. The XmlSerializer takes the temporary object and stores there the Data.

Is there any other solution to serialize and deserialze an Interface? In the class Foo I know its an Instance of bar. But the Interface forces me to Implement an List of IBarInterface.

**The Interface for `Foo`:**

```
public interface IFooInterface
{
    ObservableCollection<IBarInterface> BarList { get; }
}
```

**The Implementation of `IFooInterface`:**

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Bar))]
[XmlRoot(ElementName ="Foo")]
public class Foo : IFooInterface
{
    ObservableCollection<IBarInterface> barList;

    [XmlElement(ElementName ="BarList")]
    public ObservableCollection<Bar> XmlBarList
    {
        get
        {
            // Creates an temporary Object, so it won't work
            return this.BarList.Select(bar => bar as Bar).ToList();
        }
        set
        {
             this.BarList = new ObservableCollection<IBarInterface>(value);
        }
    }

    // Won't work out of the box with XmlSerializer
    // so I Ignore it
    [XmlIgnore]
    ObservableCollection<IBarInterface> BarList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.barList;
        }
        set
        {
            this.barList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Interface for `Bar`:**

```
public interface IBarInterface
{
    string BarString { get; }
}
```

**The Implementation of `IBarInterface`:**

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName ="Bar")]
public class Bar : IBarInterface
{
    string BarString;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "BarString")]
    string BarString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bar;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bar = value;
        }
    }
}
```